# String iteration with numbers at the end (Beginner)

Tags: java, methods, iteration

I have a code that "deletes" all characters in a sentence that appear more than once in a row. For example:

> "Thiiis iiis aaa tesst"

I use the `charAt()` and `length()` method (It's a task for University and I am only allowed to use this two methods).
In a way it works fine but my question is:

Why do I see numbers at the end of my sentence? And can anyone tell me if or where my code is wrong?

> This is a test19212325272

Here is the code I used for this:

```
public static String reduce(String w) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length() - 1; i++) {
        if(w.charAt(i) == w.charAt(i + 1)) {
            w += w.length() - 1;
        }
        else {
            result += w.charAt(i);
        } 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is because of this `w += w.length() - 1;`. What did you try to do when you see same two characters that are adjacent?

Comment: The characters after the first one should be deleted until the next character is reached.

Comment: there are 2 t in test is that a problem

Comment: you need to remove the character not add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `w += w.length() - 1` .You don't need that.

Modified code :-

```
public static String reduce(String w) {
    if (w == null) return null;         // in case if w is NULL
    String result = "";
    result += w.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < w.length(); i++) {
        if (w.charAt(i - 1) != w.charAt(i)) {
            result += w.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Output :-**

```
Thiiis iiis aaa tesst
This is a test
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `w += w.length() - 1` when there are a two the same characters you are adding to `w` variable it length. When you remove it (and also add after for loop check if last char is the same like previous) then this code works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `if` condition at all. The following program removes duplicate characters:

```
public static String reduce(String w) {
    // make sure w is not null
    if (w == null) return null;

    String result = Character.toString(w.charAt(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < w.length(); i++) {
        if(w.charAt(i) != w.charAt(i - 1)) {
            result += w.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```